# How to generate a new map for jvectormap jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, jvectormap

I want to know how to create or generate a map for jquery plugin jvectormap http://jvectormap.com/

The project has several maps:
http://jvectormap.com/maps/

but I need I map with Australia and new Zeland divided by states. In the documentation in github https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap, it says that anyone can generate a map with this command:

```
python \
    path/to/converter.py \
    path/to/geo-data.shp \
    path/to/resulting-map.js \
    --width 900 \
    --country_name_index 4 \
    --where "ISO = 'USA'" \
    --codes_file path/to/codes-en.tsv \
    --insets '[{"codes": ["US-AK"], "width": 200, "left": 10, "top": 370}, {"codes": ["US-HI"], "width": 100, "left": 220, "top": 400}]' \
    --minimal_area 4000000 \
    --buffer_distance -3000 \
    --simplify_tolerance 1000 \
    --longtitude0 10w \
    --name us
```

but I think is outdates, cause I downloaded http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/ as the documentation says, but of course didn't work.

Can anyone tell me how to generate a map with australia and new zeland divided by states for jvectormap??

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just in case anyone will need the same.
To run converter, you need (this instruction is valid for Windows environment):

- download and install [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) (use Express Desktop Install)
- download desired shape file ([this](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/) natural data file works fine).
- put [anyjson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/anyjson/0.2.0) to converter directory
- create **makemap.bat** in converter directory, like this:

`python ^

        converter.py ^

        ../../ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp.shp ^

        test-map.js ^

        --width 400 ^

        --where "ISO_3166_2 = 'RU-' and code_hasc!=''" ^

        --country_name_index 12 ^

        --country_code_index 18 ^

        --minimal_area 4000000 ^

        --buffer_distance -0.5 ^

        --simplify_tolerance 10000 ^

        --longitude0 54.8270 ^

        --name russia`

- run OSGeo4W shell (it will be added to start menu)
- run makemap.bat
- enjoy generated map

As a sample output attaching this fiddle with russian map generated using steps mentioned above http://jsfiddle.net/dyP4c/3/

About parameters (what I know)

**where** condition is used to filter out shapes from shapefile using shapefile attributes
**simplify_tolerance** will affect map quality and size
**country_name_index** index of REGION NAME attribute in shapefile or column in tab separated file if codes_file is used
**country_code_index** index of REGION CODE attribute in shapefile or column in tab separated file if codes_file is used
**codes_file** is tab separated file (if you want to use names/codes not from shapefile)
**longitude0** is longitude of area ([used this](http://www.google.com/search?q=russian%20longitude))
**name** is map name

P.S.: OSGeo4W package has nice [Quantium GIS Browser](https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/qgis_browser/qgis_browser.html) to browse shapefile attributes. You can try to search other shapefiles on the web (not only natural data) to convert to jvectormap

Comment: Where is converter.py located? I installed OSGeo4W (Express Desktop) but I can't see such file. There are only EpochConverter.py, StrConverter.py and UnitDblConverter.py

Comment: @akapelko Converter.py is part of jvectormap source code -https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap/tree/master/converter . OSGeo4W is just required to run this python script.

Comment: Hi, I have followed the steps mentioned in this post, but i am facing an issue. Please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520807/the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-geos-dll

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the command you've written. It looks like it's only for US maps:

```
--insets '[{"codes": ["US-AK"], "width": 200, "left": 10, "top": 370}, {"codes": ["US-HI"], "width": 100, "left": 220, "top": 400}]' \
```

I don't know the answer, but that's where I'd start fixing the issue

Comment: yep you are right.. but the question is how to know what parameters should be in command... also where I can find maps to convert.. thanks