# jvectormap country code index, country name index parameters information needed

Tags: jvectormap, country-codes

I was working with map converter for Bangladesh, i have few shape files. But i am having problem understanding following parameters while creating map Js form shapefile.
Need information from where i can find these parameters value for my country ..Bangladesh.

```
 --country_code_index              (where to find?)
--country_name_index   (where to find?)
--codes_file ( explain pls)
```

I spent whole day converting a shape file to map, using the conversion script, map js file generated, but the map is not loading properly :(
I guess i made mistake with the above parameters.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Country_code_index (the "key") and country_name_index (the "value") are basically the respective column numbers in the .dbf file associated with your .shp (first column = 0).
I never had to specify the codes_file though: if your dealing with .shp, maybe you should take a look [here](https://github.com/datag/jvectormap/wiki/Map-converter-notes), it should be quite helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

visit the link http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2009/03/using-image-maps-in-javascript-a-demo-application/

and for jvectormap see the thread [How to generate a new map for jvectormap jquery plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068645/how-to-generate-a-new-map-for-jvectormap-jquery-plugin?rq=1)

Hope it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

You can use "QGIS Browser" to determine

> --country_code_index
>
> --country_name_index

open your shape file in QGIS Browser in the attributes tab you can find the values.

Remember the indexes are starting from 0.

If you have shapefile for here 
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/
you don't need this

> --codes_file

In your case try these

```
python ^
   converter.py ^
   ./input/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.shp ^
   ./output/jvectormap.bd.js ^
     --width 900 ^
     --country_name_index 49 ^
     --country_code_index 1 ^
     --buffer_distance -0.4 ^
     --where "iso_a2 = 'BD'" ^
     --projection mill ^
     --simplify_tolerance 1000 ^
     --name Bangladesh ^
     --language en
```

For reference
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90783/how-to-generate-jvectormap-for-united-kingdom-uk/91071#91071