# convert .shp file to map with jvectormap-1.2.2

Tags: dictionary, svg, jvectormap

I follow [this](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/gis-converter/) document and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068645/how-to-generate-a-new-map-for-jvectormap-jquery-plugin/13520307#13520307) question.

I have downloaded **ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces** files but I can not find

country_code_index (for Iran Or other country) in it.
I use this command  in ubuntu command line :

> ogrinfo ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.dbf -al > Out.txt

out.txt's content is :
[image]

How to find `--country_code_index` AND `--country_name_index` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through [Map-converter-notes](https://github.com/datag/jvectormap/wiki/Map-converter-notes)  which has very good information about all the steps required to generate a new map from public data.

Linux users can install a very handy tool SAGA-GIS to generate required shape file and then use [converter.py](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/gis-converter/) to generate map to use with [jvectormap.com](http://jvectormap.com) plugin.

country_code_index is the index of attribute which will be used as code name for specific region on map and country_name_index is the attribute which will be shown as label of region on map. Attributes chosen for these should have unique values in map data table.